# Compound find (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, search, visual-studio-2012

I have a lot of C++ files across many projects in visual studio. I would like to search for a particular string inside a given function. e.g.:

```
virtual void BaseClass :: refresh() { ;}

// this is the result I want:
virtual DerivedClassA :: refresh() { ... theString ... }  

virtual DerivedClassB :: refresh () { ... }

// this is another match:
virtual DerivedClassC :: refresh () { theString ... }
```

So I'm looking for a search tool which will allow me to do this 'find within function' search. I'm using Windows, so the tool has to run under that. There may be other instances of 'theString' in other functions which I need to ignore.

I'm also presuming this isn't possible with visual studio, but is there some plugin I can use?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Enable the regex search on the search tool.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - could you be more specific? I don't think this helps for functions with a multi-line body. Say I have
    virtual DerivedClassD :: refresh()
    {
        for (...) {...}
        theString;
    }

Comment: I cannot be more specific with the answer because I'm not used to `regex`, I'm just thinking that using `regex` in the search dialog could help you... the only `regex` i've tested is `[ ]*\:\:[ ]*refresh\(\)[ ]*{[.\n]*thestring[.\n]*}` but it doesn't works.

Comment: OK, thanks all the same - gives me something to try. I am reasonably familiar with regex.